# Is this a favorable response from the professor?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-assistantship

I am applying to a thesis-based Master's program where the professor hires the students in their research group. I've interviewed the professor on skype and we have emailed each other after the interview half a dozen times. Now, after a few months, I asked him when the admission decisions are sent and he wrote me:

*Dear X, I am currently reviewing all the people who showed interest in my research group. The results will be announced after I am done with this in the next month. Thank you for your patience and understanding*

So, does this mean I am still being considered for the research group or is this a polite rejection?

Comment: That reply could have gone to 20 or 50 others interested... So don’t stop looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it isn't possible to be certain, I'd think it was not a rejection. There is little reason to "string you along" if you've been rejected. It wasn't especially positive, of course, but there might be several reasons for that - especially if you haven't met in person. He may just be responding to an email, not to you as a person.

But, if you have other options, keep them open. As they say in baseball: It ain't over 'til it's over.

Answer (score 9):

There is no hidden information in the message.

Comment: Most likely, but one cannot be certain.